# Why is this invalid syntax, python

Tags: python, syntax-error

`attrs` is a `list` of `tuples` (or really a list of anything)

So when I run this code,

```
if "gold" in s for s in attrs:
    print "something"
```

it returns

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What is my Syntax Error?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a genex there.

```
if any('gold' in s for s in attrs):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a for-loop like that.  It's just not how Python's syntax works.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
for s in attrs:             # For each attribute...
    if "gold" in s:         # ...if "gold" is in it...
        print "something"   # ...print the message.
```

or maybe this:

```
if any("gold" in s for s in attrs):  # If any of the attributes have "gold"...
    print "something"                # ...print the message.
```

I think the problem is that you saw a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), both of which have similar syntax.  However, those only work if they are properly enclosed (i.e. in `[]` or `()`).

Answer (score 1):

This just looks better:

```
if "gold" in s:
    for s in attrs:
        print "something"
```

Though I am really unsure of how this would work. are you sure you don't want:

```
for s in attrs:
    if "gold" in s:
        print "something"
```

I know from a golf standpoint one line solutions are better but this may be easier to read

Comment: Are you sure that first code block would run? The second one makes sense.

Comment: @myacobucci it would have to depend on whether s was assigned before hand then reassigned in the loop... I wanted to stick to the OP's original idea but to be honest I don't know how that would work

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if "gold" in (x for x in attrs):
    print "something"
```

Same as:

```
 gen = (x for x in attrs):

 if "gold" in gen:
    print "something"
```

Comment: So the `any` statement makes sense, it basically means if any of these are true. This makes sense for an if statement. But how does adding the parenthesis change the syntax from what I have written?

Comment: `(x for x in attrs)` returns a generator. You can do `[x for x in attrs]` to return a list